# How to connect to database once and do many queries thru a single connection using SQLX module in my Go web application?

Tags: postgresql, go, pointers, sqlx

My project is web back-end that using Go http framework: *gin-gonic/gin* module.
[My example repository](https://gitlab.com/manazoid/sqlx-test.git)

**PostgreSQL database**

I am using a remote hosted database (Render) and *jmoiron/sqlx* module to connect to PostgreSQL database. With the local database exactly the same story, the same errors. But unlike a local database, hosting provides metrics in your personal account. I observe there the use of the CPU, RAM and the number of connections at the current moment.

**Connection**

```
// db is *sqlx.DB that contain standard *sql.DB
db, err := sqlx.Open("postgres", fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=%s",
    postgresConfig.Host, postgresConfig.Port, postgresConfig.Username, postgresConfig.Password, postgresConfig.DBName, postgresConfig.SSLMode))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

I call the sqlx.Open() method and then pass the connection pointer to all my necessary functions that use the database. As expected, the connection succeeds. But then I expected one single connection and execution of sql queries with one connection in the metric.

**SQL query**

```
// this is how database use
func (r *AuthPostgres) CheckSession(identifier string) (*models.Account, error) {
    var account models.Account
    if err := r.db.Get(&account, `select login, password, credits from "Account" 
         where login=$1`,
        identifier); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &account, nil
}
```

Actually this is not quite as expected. When my application executes sql queries, the number of connections grows. This shouldn't happen.

Screenshots. Amount of connections metrics:

1. [Amount of connections grows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLXM0.jpg)
2. [I turned off the go application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM0IP.jpg)

**What I already tried**

I have a project that is slightly larger than this example, but in [this repository](https://gitlab.com/manazoid/sqlx-test.git) I have outlined exactly what one function looks like and how it connects to the database. And I already tried to tweaking this:

1. Add or remove pointers (*, &)
2. Different database (localhost -> remote)
3. Change max_connections in postgres config file (localhost)
4. Set time-out for connection
5. Set max open/idle connection limit

These not work for me. I would like get a single connection and do sql queries many times per minute.

**Logs**

Errors that I recieved from logs during testing in different ways. I have highlighted the most important. These were repeated in different order and in different combinations.

1. FATAL: sorry too many clients already
2. pq: out of memory
3. fatal error: out of memory allocated heap arena metadata

Comment: *"I would like get a single connection and do sql queries many times per minute."* -- You can do only one query at a time per one connection, so it's likely *not* what you would like. But if you do want a single connection then you should use something like `pgx` instead of `sqlx`. The `sqlx` package utilizes `*sql.DB` which is connection **pool**; it will attempt to open a new connection every time if all the pool's connections are active, i.e. not idle.

Comment: mkopriva Thank you for advice. But `pgx` has little functionality for scanning to struct. For me this feature of `sqlx` module was decisive when choosing a module for connecting to the database. I added an answer and will stay to use `sqlx`.

Answer (score 1):

`sql.DB` is a poor name for that struct. It is not a single connection it is a [connection pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool)

That is what you need in the majority of real-life applications. Connection Poll enables concurrency and simplifies code by eliminating the need to manage connections explicitly.

You still have control over Connection Pool size and lifetime with [DB.SetMaxOpenConns](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.SetMaxOpenConns) and [DB.SetMaxIdleConns](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.SetMaxIdleConns) methods.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: Using context and open connection pool with sqlx.ConnectContext().

```
-   // db is *sqlx.DB that contain *sql.DB
-   db, err := sqlx.Connect("postgres", fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=%s",
+   ctxTimeout, ctxCancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*3)
+   defer ctxCancel()
+
+   db, err := sqlx.ConnectContext(ctxTimeout, "postgres", fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=%s",
        postgresConfig.Host, postgresConfig.Port, postgresConfig.Username, postgresConfig.Password, postgresConfig.DBName, postgresConfig.SSLMode))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

To save resources and control idle activity in your database pool:

```
+   db.SetMaxIdleConns(5)
+   db.SetConnMaxIdleTime(10 * time.Second)
+   db.SetMaxOpenConns(95)
```

Comment: Use `db.Exec` instead of `db.Query`. The last one need own context. But `db.Exec` use the same context as parent `sqlx.ConnectContext()`.

Comment: Use of context is not necessary. It will not fix the problem of unreleased resources. It should not be the answer. If, in your actual code, you were using `Query`/`QueryRow`/`Begin`/`Prepare` (or any of their variations) and you weren't properly releasing their underlying resources, then that is the actual reason why the pool ran out of idle connections. Note that the original version of your gitlab example project used only `sqlx` specific methods which do not need the extra care of freeing resources.

Comment: @mkopriva "*only sqlx specific methods which do not need the extra care of freeing resources.*" - I thought so too. But it's differently not as expected. I need control **open connections** A little amount of idle connections were.

Comment: If my answer works. why not.